# Password processing for public APIs?

Tags: security

I do not understand some concepts of storing/processing passwords.

For example, our site has a public api for mobile application(iOS, Android, etc) with provided authentication.

No doubdt, we must not store raw passwords in the database and we must not send raw passwords between client and server, so we use hashes and salt.

This way, we encrypt passwords on client and send hashes to server. But, what if a "black hat"  steals password hash and authenticates with it to server api?

Should I hash passwords on client, send hashes, then hash them again on server?

What is the common solution of this problem?

Great thanks in advance.

Comment: You *can* also hash on the client side, but you must *always* hash on the server-side.

Comment: This question is better suited on http://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can use SSL to protect communication channel between client and server, and send password unencryped.

Second approach - to store hashed passwords (without salt) in server, and when authenticate - get random token from server (that will expire in some minutes), calculate hash from client password and use calculated hash to encode received token. Then send encoded token to server. Server does same operation but use hash stored in database instead calculating it from password. This approach has cons - needs to store password raw or hashed without salt. Or send salt to client with token.

> But, what if a "black hat" steals password hash and authenticates with it to server api?

This problem is solved by using tokens that will expire after usage.

Answer (score 1):

Do a lightweight hash client side (no salt), then rehash the hash (with unique salt) server side. Store the salt and (doubly) hashed password.

The server side hash should also use something like [pbkdf2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) or [scrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt) that can perform thousands of hashing iterations to deliberately slow down the hashing process. This helps prevent brute force attacks of the hashes by slowing down the attack process.